# Literal String substitution in python

Tags: python

Consider the below code snippet in python

```
argKey = 'actualArgument'

methodA(argKey=argVal) #invoking methodA
```

where methodA() is defined as :

```
def methodA(actualArgument, actualArgument2, actualArgument3)
```

methodA can be invoked only via named arguments ie. you invoke by specifying the argument name and passing the argument value.

--> throws an error :

```
TypeError: methodA() got an unexpected keyword argument 'argKey '
```

I want 'methodA' to be invoked by the value contained in the 'argKey' variable i.e

```
methodA(actualArgument=argVal)
```

How to get the substitution of the string into the method invocation call.?

Comment: It helps to know why you want to do this...

Answer (score 3):

To pass parameters with computed names, use a dict:

```
def foo(a, b):
  return a+b

name_of_a = 'a'
params = {name_of_a: 1, 'b': 2}
print foo(**params) # note the asterisks
```

Comment: Here are some docs from the tutorial http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists